# How to set instance variables from lambda definition when defined in different scope

Tags: ruby

I have a module with multiple methods and I want some of the to remain private. Since you can't mark them as private in module I wanted to extract the implementation to the nested class and delegate calls to this class.

I occurred a problem with setting an instance variables. The snipped code works as I would expect for initialising the `@id` value but it's not working for `@token`.

Is there any possibility to invoke method `HelpersImpl#token_initializer` from `Helpers` module that will set `@token` value on it?

And the second question, why it works when method that sets variables is defined within `Helpers` but doesn't work when defined in `HelpersImpl`?

```
module Helpers
  def init_token
    HelpersImpl.new.token_initializer.call
  end

  def init_id
    id_initializer.call
  end

  def id_initializer
    lambda do
      @id = 'id'
    end
  end

  class HelpersImpl
    def token_initializer
      lambda do
        @token = 'HelpersImpl'
      end
    end
  end

  private_constant :HelpersImpl
end

class User
  include Helpers

  def token
    init_token
    @token
  end

  def id
    init_id
    @id
  end
end

user = User.new

if user.id == 'id'
  puts 'Id - OK!'
else
  puts "Id - Wrong id: #{user.id.inspect}"
end

if user.token == 'HelpersImpl'
  puts 'Token - OK!'
else
  puts "Token - Wrong token: #{user.token.inspect}"
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  def init_token
    instance_exec(&HelpersImpl.new.token_initializer)
  end
```

[instance_exec](https://apidock.com/ruby/BasicObject/instance_exec) calls the block (or lambda/proc, if you convert it to a block with `&`) passing along the caller's value of `self`.